# How to Moq methods that return "this"

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have an interface

```
interface IService
{
    IService Configure();
    bool Run();
}
```

The "real" implementation does this:

```
class RealService : IService
{
    public IService Configure()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool Run()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Using Moq to mock the service creates a default implementation of `Configure()` that returns `null`.

Is there a way to setup methods in Moq that return the mocked instance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming that you are using [`Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4#who), you can simply `Setup` the mock to return itself:

```
var mock = new Mock<IService>();

mock.Setup(service => service.Configure()).Returns(mock.Object);

var testClass = new TestClass(mock.Object);
```

Then validate if the method returned what you expect:

```
Assert.AreEqual(mock.Object, testClass.DoStuff());
```

Comment: You say "Moq from Microsoft". Are you referring to [this `Moq`](https://github.com/Moq/moq4#who)?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen indeed, I should have been more accurate

Answer (score 3):

Either way will work to setup methods that return the mocked instance.

```
//Arrange
var instance = Mock.Of<IService>();//mocked instance
var mockService = Mock.Get(instance);//mock object used to setup instance functionality
//setup method to return mocked instance
mockService.Setup(m => m.Configure()).Returns(instance);
```

Or

```
//Arrange
var mockService = new Mock<IService>();//mock object used to setup instance functionality
var instance = mockService.Object;//mocked instance
//setup method to return mocked instance
mockService.Setup(m => m.Configure()).Returns(instance);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just create another Mock Object that uses the same interface and return it:

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTest1
{

    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        var serviceMock1 = new Mock<IService>();
        var serviceMock2 = new Mock<IService>();

        serviceMock1.Setup(service => service.Configure())
            .Returns(serviceMock2.Object);

        var testClass = new TestClass(serviceMock1.Object);

        Assert.IsNotNull(testClass.DoStuff());
    }
}

public class TestClass
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public TestClass(IService service)
    {
        _service = service;
    }

    public IService DoStuff()
    {
        return _service.Configure();
    }
}


public interface IService
{
    IService Configure();
    bool Run();
}

public class RealService : IService
{
    public IService Configure()
    {
        return this;
    }

    public bool Run()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```